WSL Gitkraken SSO Login Fails 1020
I have installed Gitkraken in WSL. I would like to use SSO to log in to my company's Azure Active Directory account.
After pressing Sign in with SSO -> Entering my email -> Sign in, a window opens in my browser that redirects to https://www.gitkraken.com/error?error=1020. Doing some research I couldn't find any information on error code 1020. This does not happen when signing in with SSO outside of WSL.
Are there any ways that I can log in?
